# Linux bluetooth script freezing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I am writing a script that will receive a command via Bluetooth and execute it. This is working correctly but after a random number of times the script will just hang after the Bluetooth device disconnects.

This is the script that I am currently running for testing.

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
sudo sdptool add --channel=22 SP
sudo rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 22 &

while [ true ]
do
 echo starting loop
 while [ true ]
 do
  count=$(rfcomm -a | wc -l)
  if [ "$count" = "1" ];
  then
   break;
  fi
 done
 sleep 0.5
 echo "End of loop."

 device=$(rfcomm show /dev/rfcomm0 | awk '{print $4}')
 sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0 > myCommand
 sudo chmod 777 myCommand
 more myCommand
 possible=$(cat myCommand)
 if [ "$possible" = "exit" ]
 then
  sudo poweroff
  break;
 fi
 ./myCommand
 echo "Finished executing!"
 echo ""
done
```

This is the results of one of my tests. It hangs after Disconnected is written and has happened after the second up to the thirtieth time.

```
Serial Port service registered
starting loop 0
Waiting for connection on channel 22
Connection from 22:22:7C:8B:61:86 to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
End of loop.
Disconnected
Waiting for connection on channel 22
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/pan
Finished executing!

starting loop 1
Connection from 22:22:7C:8B:61:86 to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
End of loop.
Disconnected
Waiting for connection on channel 22
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/pan
Finished executing!

starting loop 2
Connection from 22:22:7C:8B:61:86 to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
End of loop.
Disconnected
Waiting for connection on channel 22
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/pan
Finished executing!

starting loop 3
Connection from 22:22:7C:8B:61:86 to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
End of loop.
Disconnected
Waiting for connection on channel 22
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/pan
Finished executing!

starting loop 4
Connection from 22:22:7C:8B:61:86 to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
End of loop.
Disconnected
```

*Update:
I commented out line 25 `sudo chmod 777 myCommand` and am no longer having the script freeze without any message. It is now getting a Segmentation fault that is changing what line number caused it.

```
./bluetooth.sh: line 36:  2753 Segmentation fault      sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0 > myCommand
```

Comment: I was wondering if the bluetooth chip also handles the wifi?  As I have add a lot of trouble with the simultaneous activity with wifi and bluebooth.